# Separate a string with characters, spaces and integers into string and integer in C

Tags: c, string

I am looking for a way to separate a string into a string and integer at the last space in C

```
"121 212 27387" into "121 212" and 27387
"pur ple 16091" into "pur ple" and 16091
"98!=76 54321 22143" into "98!=76 54321" and 22143
```

the integer can be extracted with atoi(strrchr()), but I don't know how the string can be extracted, sscanf won't work, because it stops at the first space

Comment: You don't need to *extract* the first string. You already *have* the first string. It is the string from the beginning to the position of the last space.

Comment: yes but I need to know how I can extract that string

Comment: Depending on the storage of your string, you can just replace the space where you want to split it by a 0 byte. That will terminate the string at this position. Or you could use `strncpy` to copy the first part of that string into another memory location. In that case you also have to add terminating 0 byte into the destination memory.

Comment: If you want to copy it to a different location skipping the spaces, just do that with a simple loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to locate the last occurrence of the space. Assign a pointer to the address. From there you can convert the number to an integer and you can  copy the string to a new variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char substring[32];
    char string[] = "121 212 27387";
    char *p = strrchr(string, ' ');
    size_t distance = p - &string[0];
    int num = atoi(p);
    
    strncpy(substring, string, distance);
    
    printf("num = %d\n", num);
    printf("distance = %d\n", distance);
    printf("substring = %s\n", substring);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked thank you :)